# Multiple inclusion. What would happen if it is allowed?

Tags: c++, header, c-preprocessor, multiple-inclusions

I'm new to C++ and have been through a lot of articles about multiple inclusion resolutions. I have come across both MACRO and `#pragma once` method, even experimented them by myself to solve compile time error. However, none of them mention the possible problems caused by them.

---

What would happen if multiple inclusion is allowed?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have read already, I couldn't find the answer though.

Comment: Multiple inclusion **is** allowed. Duplicating definitions, which is one of the common consequences of multiple inclusion, is not allowed.